# Multilevel header UI issue in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

My implementation of jqgrid works fine.But there is a slight UI problem in case of multilevel headers.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue.I am using free jqgrid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with some additional free space over level 2 for example. Moreover I personally fine very difficult to find information in such multilevel header.

Comment: I am talking about the space above 'level 2s' in middle column and above 'level 3' in last column in the image shared.

Answer (score 0):

I personally fine very difficult to find information in such multilevel header. I don't see any advantages from adding free space over "level2" text, but in general you can do this by usage empty strings in the `titleText`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/MultilevelHeaders1.htm) displays the results like on the picture below

[image]

It uses the code

```js
.jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
    useColSpanStyle: true,
    groupHeaders: [
        { startColumnName: "invdate", numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: "level1" },
        { startColumnName: "amount", numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: "level1" },
        { startColumnName: "note", numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: "level1" }
    ]
})
.jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
    useColSpanStyle: true,
    groupHeaders: [
        { startColumnName: "invdate", numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: "level2" },
        { startColumnName: "amount", numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: "" },
        { startColumnName: "tax", numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: "" },
        { startColumnName: "note", numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: "" }
    ]
})
.jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
    useColSpanStyle: true,
    groupHeaders: [
        { startColumnName: "amount", numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: "level2" },
        { startColumnName: "tax", numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: "level2" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I am sorry if I was unambiguous in my question.But I want to remove the white spaces.They are displaying by default for me.

Comment: @johndoe: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean. You can design the header how you want just staying within limits of HTML `<table>`. For example, you can make some borders not visible like [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/MultilevelHeaders2.htm) and get practically the same results like on your original picture. You should understand that it's no more the functionality of jqGrid. You have just `<thead>` of HTML and you can modify it like you need or to set any CSS styles, which you need. Nobody will implement youth *specific wishes*. You should do this yourself.